# How to not use encrypted cookies in laravel?

Tags: cookies, encryption, laravel-4

I've upgraded Laravel from 4.0 to 4.1. My application sets Cookies, which I also use in javascript. Now they get automatically encrypted, thus not readable anymore in javascript.
I can't find how to disable the encryption for particular cookies When I try to set them with PHP setcookie native function, they don't persist.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: What about `Crypt::decrypt($encryptedValue);` ?

Comment: The problem is I can't set cookies that are not encrypted. Cookies that are set with Laravels Cookie::make() are encrypted automatically, Cookies set with native setcookie() function are completely discarded

Comment: There is a hacky way, example given in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3440

Comment: For laravel 5 the solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029385/unencrypted-cookie-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it setting the cookies with php native function setcookie in the app::after filter.
In each request I re-set the cookies because laravel clears them while processing the request.