# Unencrypted cookie in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I need to read a cookie in JS set by my Laravel app. Is there a way to do this in Laravel (as opposed to setting it directly through PHP) without overriding classes?

Comment: No, the front end has no way to decrypt them. The only way to make them accessible by the front end would be to set them via the default php method.

Comment: Why don't you pass them as a variable to your view? Or if you need it to be a JS variable, you can use laravel package that passes variables to window. global variable, or you can request them via AJAX call.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

See the `EncryptCookies` Middleware - this allows you to set the exceptions; that is, cookies that are not to be encrypted.

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies as BaseEncrypter;

class EncryptCookies extends BaseEncrypter
{
    /**
     * The names of the cookies that should not be encrypted.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'my_cookie'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it... And I kept wondering why my cookies was plain text :D

Comment: tried this with `laravel_session` cookie, but it's still encrypted

Comment: Is extending the middleware the only way to achieve this? `EncryptCookies` exposes a `disableFor` method to modify the `except` property but I'm unsure at which point I'm suppose to call that method.

Comment: @Bower, buddy your question is answered even though it's a lil late.

Comment: @ssi-anik Thank you for outlining techniques for achieving that!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is perfectly fine.

But I am writing the other ways of the same thing as pointed out in the comment by @Bower. As it's a lengthy approach, rather than putting in a comment, I am writing a full answer.

To use the `disableFor` method to do the same thing you can follow any of the following approaches.

- You register the `EncryptCookies` in the service container. And call `disableFor` after the instantiation.

```php
// use App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies;
// use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter;

$this->app->bind(EncryptCookies::class, function ($app) {
    return tap(new EncryptCookies($app->make(Encrypter::class)), function ($middleware) {
        $middleware->disableFor('laravel_session');
    });
});
```

- You can use the `afterResolving` event of the service container.

```php
$this->app->afterResolving(EncryptCookies::class, function ($middleware) {
    $middleware->disableFor('laravel_session');
});
```

**AND, BOTH THE APPROACHES ARE COUNTER-INTUITIVE** and don't make sense at all. Both of them add the complexity of hiding the code that you don't usually look at when debugging, IMHO.