# Laravel same cookie values

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I have problem with setting cookies. After I redirect I want to put some data in cookies for client side and its working but problem is cookie values.

I use that form to set cookies:

```
return redirect($url)
                ->withCookie(cookie('cookieA', 'valueA'))
                ->withCookie(cookie('cookieB', 'valueB'));
```

And after that client redirects to `$url` and when I sneak into cookies I see these values:

```
XSRF-TOKEN : eyJpdiI6ImxEUko5T0EzVG1cLzRLa09sQk0rZHdB...
cookieA : eyJpdiI6ImxEUko5T0EzVG1cLzRLa09sQk0rZHdB...
cookieB : eyJpdiI6ImxEUko5T0EzVG1cLzRLa09sQk0rZHdB...

laravel_session : L7hsdCD6hQBvX1FDM2biFZ3As...
```

It seems that somehow Laravel changes cookie value.

I have tried :

```
Cookie::queue('cookieA', 'valueA', 45000);
withCookie(cookie()->forever('cookieA', 'valueA'));
```

still same result

Comment: Did you set your cookies as encrypted by default? You will find it in your session.php 'secure' value.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies set via Laravel are encrypted/signed. If you use

```
$cookieAValue = Cookie::get('cookieA');
```

in Laravel, you'll get the actual value of the cookie. If you use your browser's devtools to view the cookie you'll see the encrypted value.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#cookies

Answer (score 1):

This problem solved my problem:

[Unencrypted cookie in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029385/unencrypted-cookie-in-laravel)

in `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies` 
i added my cookies names in `protected $except = [];`

now its working c:

Answer (score 0):

you can use setcookie function it set cookie without encrypting

```
setcookie('CookieName', 'CookieValue', 'CookieLifeTime','CookieRootDirectory');
```