# Using PHP $_COOKIE in Laravel to access Cookie. Yea or nay?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to access cookies in my Laravel project; the cookies are saved before by another developer, I just need to fetch then and use later.
by using. I am being to get cookies using' PHP'S $_COOKIE[] easily. Please tell would it be a good practice to cookie this way in my scenario or there can be a better alternative?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you use Laravel's abstractions?!

Comment: If the cookies were set outside of Laravel then you can't use Laravel's cookie helpers because Laravel encrypts and base64-encodes cookies. The question is do you really want to trust cookies that were set in plain text outside of Laravel within your Laravel project?

Comment: i smell an idea to share cookies between websites.. which is doesnt feel good..

Comment: I would go for `$value = $request->cookie('name');` see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#cookies). And if the cookie is not encrypted you can exclude it from encryption see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029385/unencrypted-cookie-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel's functions.

```
request()->cookie('cookie_name')
```

or

```
cookie('cookie_name')
```